# JavaScript Get border style of HTML Table Object

Tags: javascript, css

I'm writing some JavaScript that wraps a table in a div.  I would like to give the div element the same border style as the source table.

I should be able to programmatically query the table in the DOM and get it's border settings, but when I check the table style object's properties at runtime, they are empty strings.

How would I copy the existing element's style settings?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Source Code

---

HTML TEST CODE

```
        <table id="tbWorking" class="tbTest">
            <tr class="trTest">
                <th class="tdTest">Col1</th>
                <th class="tdTest">Col2</th>
            </tr>  
            <tr class="trTest">
                <td class="tdTest">a</td>
                <td class="tdTest">b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trTest">
                <td class="tdTest">c</td>
                <td class="tdTest">d</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trTest">
                <td class="tdTest">e</td>
            </tr>        
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="TempTestingTables.js"></script>
```

---

CSS Classes

```
    .tbTest
    {
        empty-cells: show;    
        border-collapse:separate; /* Table and Cell borders are unique */

        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:Navy;

        background-color:#DDDDDD; /* Colour of gaps between cells */
        color:Black; /* Text colour */
    }

    .trTest
    {
        background-color:#DAD7FA;
    }

    .tdTest
    {
        padding:150px;

        border-color:#7D72FC;
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;    
    }
```

---

JavaScript local to the page

```
    // Set a custom flag to indicate that the document has not yet loaded
    onLoad.loaded = false;
    // Register a function on the window object that sets the flag true when the document is loaded
    onLoad(function () { onLoad.loaded = true; });
    // This should then allow the FC function addEvent() to browser-agnostically 
    // register handlers for controls on startup

    // Once the page has loaded, set the background colour of the order ticket
    // based on the Buy/Sell selection
    onLoad(prepareTables());

    function prepareTables() {
        // Function to prepare the tables are scrollable
        prepTable("tbWorking",2);
    }

    function prepTable(sTable, rowsToShow) {

        // Pass in a table, and the number of data rows, not including the header, to display

        var tableSource = document.getElementById(sTable);
        if (tableSource == null) { return; }

        var rowHeight = GetTableRowHeight(sTable);

        var countRows = tableSource.rows.length;
        if (countRows == null || countRows == 0)
            return;

        // There is at least one row

        // Copy the table
        var tableCopy = tableSource.cloneNode(true);
        tableCopy.id = sTable + "_header";

        // Delete all except the first row
        var i = 1;
        for(;i < countRows;++i)
        { tableCopy.deleteRow(1); }

        // Insert the copy above the source table
        (tableSource.parentNode).insertBefore(tableCopy, tableSource);

        // Get the height of the header for later when we need to account for it in the wrapper tableDiv element
        var heightHeader = tableCopy.offsetHeight;


        // Move top row to the end of the table
        var rowHeaderCopy = tableCopy.rows[0].cloneNode(true); // copy the row
        rowHeaderCopy.style.visibility = "hidden"; // stop the row being displayed, but still let it contribute to layout
        tableSource.appendChild(rowHeaderCopy);

        // Hide the first row of the source table
        //tableSource.rows[0].style.display = "none"; 
        // Re-think: Delete the first row of the source table to stop it jiggering the sorting
        tableSource.deleteRow(0);


        // Wrap the source table in a div tag that is fixed size, to give us vertical scrolling on the body only   

        var bodywrapper = document.createElement("div");
        bodywrapper.id = "divBody_" + sTable;
        bodywrapper.style.overflow = "auto";

        var heightRequired = rowsToShow * rowHeight;
        bodywrapper.style.height = heightRequired + "px";

        var widthTableSource = tableSource.offsetWidth;
        var widthRequired = widthTableSource + getScrollBarWidth();
        bodywrapper.style.width = widthRequired + "px";

        // Get the border style of the table and make the div have the same style,
        // And then turn off the border style of the body (maybe, still designing).
        //var border = tableSource.style.getAttribute("border-width"); // Attempt to read style FAILED
        //var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(tableSource, ""); // Attempt to read Computed Style FAILED
        //bodywrapper.style.border = "black 1px solid"; // Hard coded bodge

        // The node to wrap is the tableSource
        tableSource.parentNode.insertBefore(bodywrapper, tableSource);
        tableSource.parentNode.removeChild(tableSource);
        bodywrapper.appendChild(tableSource);

        // Wrap the whole lot in another DIV element to give us horizontal scrolling for header and body
        var tablewrapper = document.createElement("div");
        tablewrapper.id = "divTable_" + sTable;
        tablewrapper.style.overflow = "auto";

        // Height of the outer wrapping DIV is the header height, plus body height, plus one scrollbar
        tablewrapper.style.height = 1 + getScrollBarHeight() + heightHeader + heightRequired + "px"; 

        // Width of the out DIV is default, 100%, so that scrollbar only appears 
        // if table is wider than available screen real estate.

        tableCopy.parentNode.insertBefore(tablewrapper, tableCopy); // Put the tablewrapper DIV in front of the header
        tableCopy.parentNode.removeChild(tableCopy); // Cut the header out
        bodywrapper.parentNode.removeChild(bodywrapper); // Cut the table body out
        tablewrapper.appendChild(tableCopy); // Add the header to the contents of the tablewrapper DIV
        tablewrapper.appendChild(bodywrapper); // Add the table body to the contents of the tablewrapper DIV
    }

    function GetTableRowHeight(sTable) {
        var table = document.getElementById(sTable);
        if (table == null) { return 32; }
        var countRows = table.rows.length;
        var heightTable = table.offsetHeight+1;
        return (heightTable / countRows);
    }
```

---

Common JavaScript

```
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Invoke functions once the document is loaded
    // 
    // Usage: 
    // Start by setting a flag to indicate that the document is not yet loaded...
    //     onLoad.loaded = false;
    // Then register a function to set the flag when the document loads...
    //     onLoad(function(){ onLoad.loaded=true; });
    //
    function onLoad(f) {
        if (onLoad.loaded)
            window.setTimeout(f, 0);
        else if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", f, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent("onload", f);
    }
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Graphics Functions

    // Sometimes you have to account for scrollbar widths etc.  
    function getScrollBarWidth() {
        var inner = document.createElement('p');
        inner.style.width = "100%";
        inner.style.height = "200px";

        var outer = document.createElement('div');
        outer.style.position = "absolute";
        outer.style.top = "0px";
        outer.style.left = "0px";
        outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        outer.style.width = "200px";
        outer.style.height = "150px";
        outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
        outer.appendChild(inner);

        document.body.appendChild(outer);
        var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
        outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
        if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

        document.body.removeChild(outer);

        return (w1 - w2);
    };


    // Sometimes you have to account for scrollbar widths etc.  
    function getScrollBarHeight() {
        var inner = document.createElement('p');
        inner.style.height = "100%";
        inner.style.width = "200px";

        var outer = document.createElement('div');
        outer.style.position = "absolute";
        outer.style.top = "0px";
        outer.style.left = "0px";
        outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        outer.style.width = "150px";
        outer.style.height = "200px";
        outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
        outer.appendChild(inner);

        document.body.appendChild(outer);
        var h1 = inner.offsetHeight;
        outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        var h2 = inner.offsetHeight;
        if (h1 == h2) h2 = outer.clientHeight;

        document.body.removeChild(outer);

        return (h1 - h2);
    };


    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

---

SOLUTION:

The function below should agnostically query the style object of the element and return what's required.  JQuery would be more reliable of course, no question of that.  I've decided not to try borrowing the table's border as it makes the whole operation very complex and error prone, for what is effectively just a nice edge.  But, the function below was useful, others may also find it helpful.  Bear in mind that IE returns em's and percents if that was how the style was set, it does not convert to px for you.  After all, why would you want that? (ha ha sorry).

```
    // Custom version, reverses the if-clause logic to test for IE9 first, 
    // as IE9 does not return null for getComputedStyle.
    // CREDIT: Robert Nyman (search using getStyle,oElm,strCssRule)
    function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule) {
        var strValue = "";
        if (oElm.currentStyle) {
            strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1) {
                return p1.toUpperCase();
            });
            strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
        }
        else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "");
            strValue = style.getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
        }

        return strValue;
    }
```

Comment: How are you checking these settings?

Comment: Checking using Visual Studio 2010 runtime debugging of JavaScript, with an F9 break at the point where the table element is being queried.  Table is an asp:GridView rendered to it's underlying table html code, but for testing I am using a small hand-cobbled table in declarative HTML, to remove any ASP problems from the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that, rather than give both the table and the div the same class, then put the border stylings in that class, rather than inline on the table?

Also, when are you checking the style object's properties? How? Need to see your code. If you're trying to get those styles before the DOM is ready (like before DOM.onload is fired, in some cases), then the objects will not be ready and you won't get any values back.

EDITED

Ok, given the code above, could I interest you in a slight refactor of your CSS? :)

Let's take this:

```
.tbTest
{
    empty-cells: show;    
    border-collapse:separate; /* Table and Cell borders are unique */

    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:Navy;

    background-color:#DDDDDD; /* Colour of gaps between cells */
    color:Black; /* Text colour */
}
```

And separate it out so your table-specific styles are broken away from your border-styles:

```
.tbTest
{
    empty-cells: show;    
    border-collapse:separate; /* Table and Cell borders are unique */
    background-color:#DDDDDD; /* Colour of gaps between cells */
    color:Black; /* Text colour */
}

.borderSpec 
{
    border:1px solid Navy;
}
```

Add .borderSpec to your table:

```
    <table id="tbWorking" class="tbTest borderSpec">
        <tr class="trTest">
            <th class="tdTest">Col1</th>
            <th class="tdTest">Col2</th>
        </tr>
```

Now, in your Javascript, make a couple little modifications:

```
function prepTable(sTable, rowsToShow) {
    var tableSource = document.getElementById(sTable);
    if (tableSource == null) { return; }

    // clear off the borderSpec from your tableSource
    tableSource.setAttribute("class","tbTest");

    /* ... snip ... */

    // Wrap the whole lot in another DIV element to give 
    // us horizontal scrolling for header and body
    var tablewrapper = document.createElement("div");
    tablewrapper.id = "divTable_" + sTable;
    tablewrapper.style.overflow = "auto";

    // Now, add borderSpec to your wrapper-div
    tablewrapper.setAttribute("class","borderSpec");
```

What this does is remove the borderSpec from the table, and add borderSpec to your wrapper-div, so that the wrapper gets the border, the table does not.

jsFiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/35e6B/

Comment: Styling is done via CSS.  If you give the table and the div the same class (say solid 1px black) the table has a 1px border, and the div has a 1px border, giving the whole table a 2px border.

Comment: The aim is to write some JavaScript to take an existing table, and programmatically wrap a DIV around it to give it a scrollbar, without obviously altering the table too much.

Comment: Good point about the document not being ready.  I use code from David Flanagan's O'Reilly JavaScript book, that uses an onLoad() function to trigger my JS function only once the DOM has fired the load event and the doc is ready to manipulate.

Comment: The thing is that transferring styles manually makes your logic brittle... separating them into your CSS, and only switching CSS classes around, is less invasive. You're also doing all of this the hard way, with old school plain old Javascript... there's nothing wrong with that, if your intent is to learn a little more about Javascript and don't want to be solely reliant on libraries like jQuery, but I guarantee you that you can cut down a lot of this code if you utilize jQuery, and it can help prevent a lot of the cross-browser mucking around that one needs to do with straight Javascript.

Comment: Ah, but then the logic becomes dependent on correctly structured CSS files.  I know that a table might, or might not, have a CSS class, if someone else is designing it, but I know that it will always end up with a computed style.  What I am looking to do is cut CSS out of the picture, so that however the table gets it's border style (CSS, declaritive in HTML, whatever) the code can say 'Whatever the tables border style is currently, pinch it, apply it to the div, and null it'.  In this way, the code is much less brittle and can steal a border style regardless.

Comment: And thanks for the reply, it is an interesting approach.  I'm sticking with JavaScript as JQuery is 'not required' to do this, I can get away without it.  I will no doubt come round to JQuery but it's not in my head yet.  Got books.

Comment: Only caution I would present at this point is that, while it's impossible to ever completely divest logic and presentation (presentation has to reflect the underlying data for the data to be displayed in a relevant manner, after all, and logic really shouldn't be serving any more data than needed for presentation), encapsulating your presentation as much as possible in your CSS will help guard against major browser issues down the road. If you tried to extend what you state to things like margins and padding, you're likely to hit nasty cross-browser render issues. Just my $.02, and good luck!

Comment: Yep, understood.  The rationale is to be able to pass on my code back to the community.  Take any table, and use a few JS funcs to convert it to a scrollable table with a static header - it seems like something a lot of people need.  In my own code, I do stick to CSS design principles as much as I can.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

use firebug or something like this to check table if dom trying "reorganize"/"repair" your code to:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and tbody contain border property.

Comment: Not sure how I would do that.  The table has no tbody tags, it's a very simple test table using only table, tr and td elements. CSS Classes are...

.tbTest 
{   empty-cells: show;         
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:Navy;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    color:Black;
}

.trTest
{
    background-color:#DAD7FA;
    border-width:8px;
    border-color:Red;
    border-style:solid;
}

.tdTest
{
    padding:15px;    
    border-color:#7D72FC;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;    
}